# Why are syscalls implemented with interrupts, instead of call gates?

Tags: x86, kernel, interrupt, system-calls

From what I understand, system calls to the OS kernel are typically implemented using a software interrupt. On x86, is there a reason this is chosen over using a call gate? Call gates seem to be the "built in" way to do exactly this: transfer control to a more privileged level. So is there a specific reason (or reasons) that call gates are not used for x86 kernels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Modern X86 operating systems are transitioning away from CALL FAR callgates. With the introduction of SYSENTER/SYSEXIT and SYSCALL/SYSRET, a new faster mechanism was introduced for control transfers for x86 programs. And as most other architectures do not support call gates, their use was rare even before these new instructions as software interrupts/traps were preferred for portability.*

See [System Calls](http://wiki.osdev.org/System_Calls) at OSDev Wiki. Another reason is *Virtualization*, see [this](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~cdall/candidacy/pdf/Bugnion2012.pdf) publication.